# How to put angular code in separate files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I put this code below in one file it works good but when I separate, then don't work just show blank.In console I get error It can't find `MainformCtrl`.

Here is how I separated that:

app.js:

```
angular.module('notifications',['yaru22.angular-timeago','ngRoute'], function($interpolateProvider) {
                $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
                $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');


        });


    angular.module('commentsApp',['notifications']);
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("comment"), ['commentsApp']);
```

commentsController.js

```
angular.module('commentsApp')
        .controller('CommentsCtrl',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
              $scope.param = $routeParams.id;
              $http.get("/api/comments/"+ $scope.param)
              .success(function(data){
               var details = [];
               $.each(data,function(index,value){
                   if(value.user){
                    $.each(value.user,function(index1,value1){
                        var new_object = $.extend({}, value, value1);
                        details.push(new_object);

                    });
                   }
               });
               $scope.formShow = function(comm){
                   comm.formWhat = !comm.formWhat;
               };

               $scope.comments = details;
              })
              .error(function(data){
                  console.log(data);
              });
          })
          .controller('MainformCtrl',function($scope){
               $scope.fwhat = false;
               $scope.MainFormShow = function(){
                   $scope.fwhat = !$scope.fwhat;
               };       
          });
```

routes.js

```
angular.module('commentsApp')
.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/project/:id', {
                    controller: 'CommentsCtrl',
                    templateUrl: '/view/comments.html'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'

                });
             //check browser support
             if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
                //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); will cause an error $location in HTML5 mode requires a  tag to be present! Unless you set baseUrl tag after head tag like so: <head> <base href="/">

             // to know more about setting base URL visit: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

             // if you don't wish to set base URL then use this
             $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                     enabled: true,
                     requireBase: false
              });
            }    
    });
```

Anyone know what is problem here?

Comment: In which order are you loading these file in your html?

Comment: app.js, routes.js, commentsController.js

Comment: Why are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Because I have one more module in app `notifications`...

Comment: when you call bootstrap - your module `commentsApp` is empty

Comment: Any way to fix that?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic, try call it after all another code run. for example you can move it to another file that include last, or event call directly in `script` tag

Comment: You are right I just need to add it on the end.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem was because: module bootsrap. To solve that I deleted this:

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("comment"), ['commentsApp']);
```

from app.js

and added it on the end of controller file, because it is last file.

@Grundy thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I've come to this problem too. :)

You just need to import them on your main html file. Don't forget the order of the elements. Here's how your HTML should look.

index.html

```
<html>

  <head>  
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Here's your html stuff -->
  <script src='angular.js'> <script>
  <script src='app.js'> <script>
  <script src='routes.js'> <script>
  <script src='commentsController.js'> <script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Don't forget to import your angular.js before your js files. Your css files should go on the head of the document and any Angular separated module should go right after angular.js. To use the $routeProvider, you need to import the [ngRoute module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) and, to use this module, you need it's specific file. You can find it [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular-route.min.js) or look to your specific version [here](https://code.angularjs.org/).

Hope it help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Browserify or Webpack to require CommonJS style modules.